# old jdk profile in maven build

Tags: java, maven

I have one maven project which is have maven compiler plugin to specify the target java version as 1.8. I want it to be able to built on jdk 1.6 as well as it was a dependency for other java 1.6 based project. How to configure maven pom file for this requirement?

Comment: If you need to have JDK 6 build you should use [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the maven documentation, include this into your POM:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  [...]
</project>
```

or configure the plugin directly (also inside your POM):

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

And do not forget to install **JDK 1.6**!

Comment: That will not work. First depending on the Maven version you are using..secondly the given [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/plugin-info.html) will need at least JDK 7 to run...Apart from that setting source/target is not enough...